# how to pass value from one function to another in c#

Tags: c#

i have a function

```
      private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
      {
         random();

      }

      private void random()
      {
         //other code
         ImageBrush background = new ImageBrush();
         background.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new                         Uri(actorUri,    UriKind.Relative));
         //other code
       }
```

i want to access that background variable in button click function
please tell me how to access that...

Comment: background variable in random function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
  {
     random();
     background.SomeMethod();

  }

  ImageBrush background = new ImageBrush();

  private void random()
  {
     //other code

     background.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new                         Uri(actorUri,    UriKind.Relative));
     //other code
   }
```

**EDIT:**

OR

```
  private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
  {
     ImageBrush bg = random();
     bg.SomeMethod()


  }



  private ImageBrush random()
  {
     //other code
     ImageBrush background = new ImageBrush();
     background.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new                         Uri(actorUri,    UriKind.Relative));
     //other code
     return background;
   }
```

Comment: Click on the Tick next to my answer to mark the question status as `answered`... and welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: when i am accessing it in one function it works perfectly but when i am accessing background variable in two functions it lost its value...?? how to get rid of this???

Comment: yeah... [waiting in anticipation]

Comment: see my edit to show how to use return value of method (function)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not make `background` an instance variable of the surrounding class?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, at all... you mean this?

```
private ImageBrush m_Background = new ImageBrush();

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    // If actorUri is stored in a TextBox, for example...
    random(textbox1.Text);
}

private void random(String actorUri)
{
    // ...
    m_Background = new ImageBrush();
    m_Background.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(actorUri, UriKind.Relative));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: the background of imagebrush type
i want to gets its value in button click function

Comment: Where is that value stored? In a textbox?

Comment: the value stored in background variable

Comment: Of course it is, but I mean... actorUri is somewhere in the form? In another control's Text? In a static variable?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it sounds like you were asking this.

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
         random();
         background.DoSomething();
    }

    ImageBrush background ;
    private void random()
    {
         //other code
         background = new ImageBrush();
         background.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new                         Uri(actorUri,    UriKind.Relative));
         //other code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    ImageBrush background = random();
}

private ImageBrush random()
{
    //other code
    ImageBrush background = new ImageBrush();
    background.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new                            Uri(actorUri,    UriKind.Relative));
    return background;
}
```